# How to decode in php?

Tags: php, laravel, hex, decode, encode

Can anyone help me to decode in human readable form? I got the file Obfuscated by YAK Pro. Unable to understand what `nAbP2` term is.

```
public function event() {
        if ($this->checkDatabaseConnection()) {
            goto nAbP2;
        }
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors(["database_connection" => trans("messages.form.db_connection_failed")]);
    nAbP2:return view("event");
    }
```

Please guide me thanks.

Comment: `nAbP2:` is a [label](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php) (defined by a programmer).

Comment: Not by a programmer, I would suspect that it was added by the obfuscator to confuse the reader. The label and goto serve no other purpose. Just moving the `return view("event");` into the conditional block would do just fine (I guess that was what the code looked like before the obfuscation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nAbP2` is a label. In the third line of the posted code you can find the `goto` statement. It jumps to the respective label. It means that it will continue code execution at the location of the label instead of just continuing with the next statement.

See [goto in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php) for details.

You probably never encountered this construct because it is generally frowned upon and will mess up the readability of your code (which makes sense for an obfuscator).

Comment: but I have many files to decode can you guide to read them?

Comment: The only thing you can do is carefully read the code and try to understand what it is doing.

Comment: What do you mean by "decode"? "Un-obfuscate"? That is not really possible. The obfuscated code is valid code. It is just a harder to read.

Comment: I mean re- obfuscate.

Comment: Of course, it is possible. But only with a lot of effort. That's the whole point of obfuscation. Still, you would only get a less confusing version of the code, never the original.